# Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'. > Process 'command 'C:\Users\DELL\Documents\flutter\bin\flutter.bat''

Tags: flutter, gradle

Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
: Error: Expected ';' after this.
});0
^

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\Users\DELL\Documents\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1005
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'C:\Users\DELL\Documents\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
  BUILD FAILED in 26s
  Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
  Exited (sigterm)

Github :  https://github.com/Pavel401/rainbow

I tried to find " });0" in all dart files but couldn't find anything.It took me 30 days of work to get here . I added the repo link for code .

Comment: Your github link is invalid(404 for me), please check.

Comment: I found the solution